# AlassetsGroup Returning wrong number of assets

Tags: ios, numbers, assets, alassetslibrary, alassetsgroup

While retrieving number of assets from AlassetsGroup, its returning wrong number of assets. I follow the instruction given on link [ALAssetsLibrary seems to return wrong number of my photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448965/alassetslibrary-seems-to-return-wrong-number-of-my-photos)

but this also doesn't worked for me.

Please give a solution

Comment: What version of iOS? Is the group composed of "shared" images (with iCloud)?